# How do I access neo4j result properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I have a neo4j query in JavaScript that return two sets of nodes:

```
session
  .run ("MATCH (user:Dealer)-[:SUPPLY]->(v) RETURN user,v")
  .then (function(result)
      {
      if ( !result.records[0]) 
       ---no records
      else {
            email=result.records[0].properties.email;  //this doesn't work
           }
```

I want to access the properties from both user and v  in a nested for loop so I need direct access to each property field. The developers manual tries to explain it but not very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Result` returns you a collection of records.

A `Record` can be compared to a row in the neo4j browser and has a simple `get` method for accessing record values, in your use case, for having the user :

```
user = result.records[0].get('user');
```

When you expect a node or a relationship to be returned, they contain a `properties` object which represent key value pairs of properties.

A node has also a `labels` property representing the labels of a node

```
email = user.properties['email'];
labels = user.labels; // returns the node labels
```